# Calling function with string as parameter

Tags: c++, x64dbg, game-hacking, calling-conventions

I'm trying to call a function in a game that makes my character sending a message.

I already called a few functions in this game but this one has a tricky parameter.

The function signature should be similar to this:

```
void Game::talkChannel(Otc::MessageMode mode, int channelId, const std::string& message)
```

This is how I define it:

```
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _talkChannel)(DWORD localplayer, uintptr_t mode, uintptr_t channelId, const std::string& message);
_talkChannel talkChannel;
talkChannel = (_talkChannel)(moduleBase + 0x79340);
```

This is how I call it:

```
talkChannel(LocalPlayer, 1, 0, "test");
```

Here's how the function looks normally:

[image]

And this is how it looks if I call it from my dll:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't looks the same, and the result in game is my character sending this message:

`ï¶test

So as I can see it will fill the message until 8 characters, and if I send more than 8 characters it won't send any message.

Trying to send as a `const char *` made me explode my brain because it looks exactly the same as the original function call:

[image]

But nothing happens ingame, no message is sent, even the call looks identical to me in debugger...

How should I call that function with this tricky parameter?

**EDIT:**

Calling as **const wchar_t*** didn't work, but it's fun to see how it differs in debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the end I just had to compile as Release.

Thanks to this information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring/

So it's just a compiler difference